# How to do conditional rendering using switch in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, switch-statement, conditional-rendering

Hello I'm trying to do switch statement in my project.I've an object image as follows

```
export const images = [
  {
    image: BASE.URL + 'Images/Plumber.png',

  },
  {
    image: BASE.URL + 'Images/electrician.png',


  },
 {
    image: BASE.URL + 'Images/ac.png',

  }
]
```

I'm fetching the list of workers from server and render it within a `Card`.So the server response only contains the name of workers.I'm trying to give images along with them.So I've written a switch statement but image is not coming along with the text.Following is my code.

```
    import { images } from './data';
    renderImage() {
        const { workType } = this.state;
        switch (workType) {
          case 'Plumber':
            return (
              <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={{ uri: images[0].image }} />
            );
          case 'Electrician':
            return (
              <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={{ uri: images[1].image }} />
            );
     case 'AC'
            return (
              <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={{ uri: images[2].image }} />
            );
        }
      }
   render(){
    const { workers,workType } = this.state;
    return(
    {workers.map((a, index) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popUpDialog(a.id, a.work_type)}>
                      <Card>
                        {this.renderImage()}
                        <Text>{a.work_type}</Text>
                      </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
              ))}
    )
    }
```

What wrong I'm doing please help me to find a solution.Thank you!

Comment: In future you could use https://npmjs.com/package/react-floco as a way to render switch statements declaratively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `console.log` your `this.state.workType` because it might not be the value you think it should be. Since you dont have a `default` case, the function returns nothing.

Also, it could be easier if you take the `workType` as a parameter for your `renderImage` function. I suspect your `this.state.workType` will not be the same with your `a.work_type` in the `workers.map` function. You can do it like this

```js
const renderImage = (workType) => {
  switch (workType) {
  ...
  }
}

//and then
   workers.map((a, index) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popUpDialog(a.id, a.work_type)}>
                      <Card>
                        {this.renderImage(a.work_type)}
                        <Text>{a.work_type}</Text>
                      </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
   ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to return the mapped component.

eg:

```
render() {
    const { workers,workType } = this.state;
    return(
        {workers.map((a, index) => {
            return(
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popUpDialog(a.id, a.work_type)}>
                    <Card>
                        {this.renderImage()}
                        <Text>{a.work_type}</Text>
                    </Card>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to go for a map and render the image in following way.

```
const WORKTYPE_TO_IMAGE = {
  Plumber: BASE.URL + 'Images/Plumber.png',
  Electrician: BASE.URL + 'Images/electrician.png',
  AC: BASE.URL + 'Images/ac.png',
};

renderImage(){
  return (
    <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} source={WORKTYPE_TO_IMAGE[this.state.workType]} />
  )
}
```

You were using Image tag thrice but now you'll only use it once (hence Do Not Repeat principle is followed). Furthermore, I really hate if/switch in my code because the requirements frequently, instead changing logic in your code, you should change only at one place (which is a constant in your case). The code will be really clean and short :)

Comment: So do I need to write a map method for `WORKTYPE_TO_IMAGE ` ?

Comment: No, its just a wrapper object for all your work type image urls

Answer (score 0):

I just give style to main view and then everything is working fine.

```
  renderImage(workType) {
    switch (workType) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
        );
      case 1:
        return (
          <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }} />
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
        );
    }
  }

  //source={{ uri: require('./1.jpg') }}
  render() {
    let workers = [{ work_type: 'Plumber' }, { work_type: 'Electrician' }, { work_type: 'AC' }];
    return (
      <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        {
          workers.map((a, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.popUpDialog(a.id, a.work_type)}>
              <View>
                {this.renderImage(index)}
                <Text>{a.work_type}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
```

I have set color as I don't have an image.